# custom column type for django create DB cache table command

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I’m currently working with a PostgreSQL database and I want to use a timestamp of type ‘timestamp(0)’. To achieve this, I’ve created a custom column type using the following code:

```
class DateTimeWithoutTZField(DateTimeField):
    def db_type(self, connection):
        return 'timestamp(0)'
```

My question is: How can I use this custom ‘timestamp(0)’ type with the DB cache table that is created by running the Django command

```
python manage.py createcachetable
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Django app, create a model that uses the custom field for the timestamp.

```
from django.db import models

class YourModel(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    value = models.TextField()
    timestamp = DateTimeWithoutTZField()
```

Finally, create the cache table using the `createcachetable` management command:

```
python manage.py createcachetable your_cache_table_name
```